# Using Azure managed identity for App Service not authorising for new SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

We have been using `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault` for some time now with success. Using the managed identity in our WebApps and an AD group to grant access to key vault.

I have updated a couple of apps to use the `Azure.Identity` package and the .Net Framework app has continued to operate, but the .Net Core 3.1 app now does not seem to pick up the credentials.

If I add an explicit `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`, and `AZURE_TENENT_ID` that corresponds to an RBAC generated service principle, it all works fine. I don't want to have to do this though and would much prefer to use the managed identity (no config floating around).

These are the packages I am now referencing:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.0.3" />
```

This is the construction code:

```
new SecretClient("name-of-vault", new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

So nothing fancy.

This is the stack trace:

---> Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed.
---> Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: Invalid response, the authentication response was not in the expected format.
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.Deserialize(JsonElement json)
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.DeserializeAsync(Stream content, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AuthenticateAsync(String[] scopes, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(Boolean isAsync, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async, AuthenticationChallenge challenge)
at Azure.Security.KeyVault.ChallengeBasedAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessCoreAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory1 pipeline, Boolean async)
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory1 pipeline, Boolean async) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory1 pipeline)
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory1 pipeline) at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequestAsync[TResult](RequestMethod method, Func1 resultFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String[] path)
at Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient.GetSecretAsync(String name, String version, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Codat.Infrastructure.SecretsProvider.SecretsProvider.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.d.MoveNext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the MSI service in the App Service instance is returning an invalid `DateTimeOffset` format.

Request:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://127.0.0.1:41601/MSI/token/?api-version=2017-09-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true";Secret="REDACTED"} -UseBasicParsing
```

Response:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {123, 34, 97, 99...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 1698
                    Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 09:26:44 GMT
                    
                    {"access_token":"REDACTED...
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 1698], [Date, Mon, 22 Jun 2020 09:26:44 
                    GMT]}
RawContentLength  : 1698

{
    "access_token": "REDACTED",
    "expires_on": "6/23/2020 9:28:43 AM +00:00",
    "resource": "https://vault.azure.net",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "client_id": "E7B39A52-REDACTED"
}
```

The format `"M/d/yyyy H:m:s tt K"` can't be parsed by the `ManagedIdentityClient`. So it seems that the bug is in the underlying azure service. I have raised an issue with the team https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12869 it has been fixed in 1.2.0-preview-4.

Comment: Fixed the issue for us!

Answer (score 0):

Should not it be like this?

```
 var sc = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://<YOUR-KEY-VAULT>.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
 Secret1 = sc.GetSecret(nameof("name-of-vault")).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`ManagedIdentityCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-dotnet) directly:

```
new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
```